# Newsletter Html email

Tags: php, html

I have prepared a newsletter with some edit textareas and some default text in it. User of my newsletter is able to edit text in text area, after which am saving the edited text when he clicks on preview button, In this page am showing all the text edited using PHP ($_POST[]). when SendNewsLetter button is clicked mail is sent but without any text in it, as am using PHP to display text. Is there any alternate way to display dynamic content in mail body. Thank in advance, Please help me out of this.

Below is the php code which is not working in email body. In preview it displays fine.

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1"  width="300px" height="auto" >
    <tr><td><?php echo set_value('input1',$_POST['input1']); ?></td></tr>
</table>
```

This is my sendemail()

```
public function newsemail(){
$this->load->library('email');
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$header = $this->load->view('index/news1','',true);
$this->email->initialize($config);
$this->email->from('info@xyz.net', 'xyz Consulting');
$this->email->reply_to('info@xyz.net','xyz Consulting');
$this->email->to('mahboob@gmail.com');
//$this->email->cc('mehboob029@gmail.com');
$this->email->bcc('xyz@gmail.com');
$this->email->subject('Newsletter');
$this->email->message( $header );
$mail = $this->email->send();
```

Comment: Where is the email script, `HTML` mail requires extra care (Content-Type), did you do that ?

Comment: [It may help you](http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/).

Comment: Please let me know if there is any alternate way without using php to send input data from one file to another. coz php is simply ignored in html email.

Comment: Found solution to my problem, any ways thanks for your time. I was not sending any data to my news1 file, when i was loading it in my mail. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Its depends on you loaded library..

there is option for HTML content or text, or body rather than message.

look into you view function.